# How to change the parent page?

Tags: django, python-3.x, wagtail

I have custom view and form for article page in admin single view. In form I have HTML5 select for change parent (section). How to change the parent page in admin edit view? I try ty use edited `python wagtail.admin.views.pages.edit`:

```py
#wagtail code 
revision = page.save_revision(
    user=request.user,
    submitted_for_moderation=is_submitting,
)
#next I try to place my code
new_parent_page_id = request.POST.get('parent_page_id')
if int(new_parent_page_id) != parent.id:
    parent = SectionPage.objects.get(id=new_parent_page_id)
    page.move(parent, pos='last-child')
    page.save()
```

and it doesn't work

wagtail version 2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
new_parent_page_id = request.POST.get('parent_page_id')
if int(new_parent_page_id) != parent.id:
    parent = SectionPage.objects.get(id=new_parent_page_id)
    page.move(parent, pos='last-child')
    page = page.specific_class.objects.get(pk=page.pk)
```

Comment: Hey Maxim. Any explanation of how/why this worked for you? I have the code but it doesn't seem to move my pages to the new parent.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, I was able to get this to work with the following code:

```
parent = Page.objects.find(...)

child = Page.objects.find(...)

child.move(parent, pos="last-child")
```